# ios app login view controller issue

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, authentication, uistoryboardsegue

I've been working on an iOS app and this app includes a login screen. This screen has two UITextField where I input the username and the password needed to login.

But I've got a problem: I've set up an "else if" to trigger an UIAlertView if the field are in blank.

The UIAlertView I've set DOES pop up but... it shows up the next View Controller.

Another issue is... The check function to check wether the username and the password are right or not is skipped and it jumps into the next View Controller as well.

This is odd because I set an "if" condition to check that the text in both UITextFields must match in order to trigger the next View Controller.

I've got the hunch that another method linked to the login action might be interfering in the process.

I'll post the segment of the code concerning the login:

```
- (void)btn_submit:(id)sender{
    NSString *user = self.usuari.text;
    NSString *pass = self.contrasenya.text;

    NSString * urlBase = @"http://www.v2msoft.com/clientes/lasalle/curs-ios/login.php?username=lluis&password=seguro";

    [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:urlBase completion:^(id json,JSONModelError *err){

JsonUser * user = [[JsonUser alloc]initWithDictionary:json error:nil];

        if(user.succeed) {

            self.user_id = user.user_id;

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login" sender:self];
        }

        else{

            NSLog(@"error");

        }
            }];
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (([self.usuari.text isEqualToString:@"lluis"]) && ([self.contrasenya.text isEqualToString:@"seguro"]))
    {

     //   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login" sender:self];

        Supermarket * supermercat = segue.destinationViewController;
        supermercat.user_id = self.user_id;

    }

    else if (_usuari.text.length == 0 || _contrasenya.text.length == 0)
    {

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alerta!"
                                    message:@"Camps buits o dades incorrectes!"
                                   delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil
          ] show];
    }

}
```

And the JsonUser class:

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@interface JsonUser : JSONModel

@property BOOL succeed;
@property int user_id;


@end
```

I know sending data unsecured is not a good idea but since it's an app that it's not going to be commercialized then it doesn't matter.

Could you try to help me out how to properly implement the login function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once prepareForSegue is called the transition will always take place. In your case, even if the username and password are incorrect. If the server is checking the username and password, so this line should be unnecessary:

```
if (([self.usuari.text isEqualToString:@"lluis"]) && ([self.contrasenya.text isEqualToString:@"seguro"]))
```

Perhaps something like this is what you're looking for, here the username and password are validated by the server. If "succeed" is true, perform the segue, otherwise the alert is shown.

```
- (void)btn_submit:(id)sender{
    NSString *user = self.usuari.text;
    NSString *pass = self.contrasenya.text;

    NSString * urlBase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.v2msoft.com/clientes/lasalle/curs-ios/login.php?username=%@&password=%@", user,  pass];

    [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:urlBase completion:^(id json,JSONModelError *err){

        JsonUser * user = [[JsonUser alloc]initWithDictionary:json error:nil];

        if(user.succeed) {

            self.user_id = user.user_id;

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login" sender:self];
        }

        else{

            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alerta!"
                                        message:@"Camps buits o dades incorrectes!"
                                       delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil
            ] show];
        }
    }];
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    Supermarket * supermercat = segue.destinationViewController;
    supermercat.user_id = self.user_id;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, now it behaves worse than before. The Alert View never shows up and it logins despite the username and password being in blank or wrong. Thanks for the suggestion but there's something else that must be fixed here or re-made.

Comment: Your url ALWAYS has the username and password set, so it will always login successfully. See edit for fix.

Comment: Good point. So maybe I should find a way to input the values into the URL at another moment in the code.

Comment: That was it indeed! Thank you very much: I was struggling so much with this and it turned out to be that easy... Thanks a lot!